# Node js redis - undefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

does not return when I call the function

```
function getSportId(lang, name, betcoid){
    redisClient.select(1, function(err,res){
        redisClient.get(lang+"_"+name, function (err, r) {
            let data = JSON.parse(r);
            return "xxx";
        });
    });
}
```

```
var print = getSportId(a,b,c);
console.log(print);
```

Console print return empty :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I tried not working

Comment: The function getSportId() doesn't have a return statement, so `print` will always be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#usage)

> Note that the API is entirely asynchronous. To get data back from the server, you'll need to use a callback.
>
> Node Redis currently doesn't natively support promises (this is coming in v4), however you can wrap the methods you want to use with promises using the built-in Node.js `util.promisify` method on Node.js >= v8;

```
const redis = require("redis");
const redisClient = redis.createClient();
const util = require('util');
util.promisify(redisClient.get).bind(redisClient);

function getSportId (lang, name, betcoid) {
    return redisClient.select(1, function (err, res) {
        redisClient.get(lang + "_" + name, function (err, r) {
            console.log(r);
        });
    });
}

getSportId('my', 'foo')
```

Also be careful about selecting database `1`. The default is `0`. The following will work if you don't have to select `1`.

```
function getSportId (lang, name, betcoid) {
    redisClient.get(lang + "_" + name, function (err, r) {
        console.log(r); //implement your callback
    });
}
```